# Puppet "define cannot be converted to Numeric" issue define + require + variables

Tags: puppet

I have created define.
everything was fine until I used my define instance (define + parameters) in 'require'

like:

```
define foo ( ... ) { ... }
...


foo { "this is title of my ${major_version}-${minor_version}" : 
...
}
```

------ until this everything was FINE ------

When I used this foo["this is title of my ${major_version}-${minor_version}"] in 'require' clausule I got:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: The value 'this is title of my major-version-minor-version' **cannot be converted to Numeric**. on node 
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also happen if you have a non-capitalized resource reference, ie

```
require => package['ehs']
```

will cause

> 'Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: The value 'ehs' cannot be converted to Numeric. on node ...

So the fix for me was to capitalize the 'P' in package like so:

```
require => Package['ehs']
```

Answer (score 0):

ops! it is simple (stupid stupid stupid !:

1. Do not use '-' as separator between variables - it is interpreted as numerical minus
   like: `$http_port = 9999 - ${instance_number}`
2. Use "Foo" instead "foo" in 'require' clause - also when you use: "Foo:Foo" (sub-classes/defines)

Comment: Yes, Puppet tries to be helpful with types and numeric operations. But you're safe from arithmetics when you embed your expression in a double quoted string. `puppet apply -e '$foo = 1 $bar = 2 notify { foo: message => "$foo-$bar" }'`